# Magento - Show simple products reviews on configurable product page

Tags: php, magento

I want to show reviews of simple products on configurable product's page.

Can anyone help?

Regards!

Comment: http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/advanced-reviews.html

Answer (score 3):

The code below will display the ratings and reviews for both configurable and simple products.  Note, you should also modify the summary at the top of the product page that shows review count & overall average rating.

Copy /app/code/core/Mage/Review/Block/Product/View.php from core to local, and modify it.
line 75 was:

```
$this->_reviewsCollection = Mage::getModel('review/review')->getCollection()
->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
->addEntityFilter('product', $this->getProduct()->getId())
->setDateOrder();
```

Change it to be:

```
if ($this->getProduct()->isConfigurable()){
    //Get both configurable product and associated simple product reviews
    $children_ids = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getChildrenIds($this->getProduct()->getId());  
    $entity_ids = array($this->getProduct()->getId(), $children_ids);

    $this->_reviewsCollection = Mage::getModel('review/review')->getCollection()
        ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
        ->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
        ->addFieldToFilter('entity_pk_value', array('in' => $entity_ids))
        ->setDateOrder();
} else {
    $this->_reviewsCollection = Mage::getModel('review/review')->getCollection()
    ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
    ->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
    ->addEntityFilter('product', $this->getProduct()->getId())
    ->setDateOrder();
}
```

Comment: There are many "local" folders in the Magento file tree.  In which one should View.php be placed?  I tried app/code/local/View.php and app/code/local/Review/Block/Product/View.php, and app/code/local/Mage/Review/Block/Product/View.php

Answer (score 0):

First of all get IDs of the products that belong to the Configurable product with this statement:

```
$children_ids = Mage::getModel ('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getChildrenIds ($_product->getId ());
```

Then traverse through all simple products and get their reviews, like this:

```
foreach ($children_ids as $child_id)
    {
        foreach ($child_id as $id)
        {
            $_items2 = Mage::getModel('review/review')->getCollection()
                        ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                        ->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
                        ->addEntityFilter('product', $id)
                        ->addRateVotes()
                        ->setDateOrder();
            $_items = $_items2->getItems ();
}}
```

Look into "view/list.phtml" to understand how to use $_items.